# "switch" only works for one "case"

Tags: c#

I checked the ActivePanel method (string nameCheck) gets all the names for "switch".
Only "БД Аксес" is executed; the remaining "cases" are not executed.

In another class, this method works.
No errors occur.
Just does not work "switch".

**Question.**
Why does not "switch" work?

---

**Code**

```
public void ActivePanel(string nameCheck)
{
    try
    {   
        switch (nameCheck)
        {

            // case "Список ссылок URL":
            case "Список":
                UrlLinkListUC urlLinkListUC = new UrlLinkListUC(settingOper);

                panel1.Controls.Clear();
                panel1.Controls.Add(urlLinkListUC);


                break;

            case "Список ссылок файлов HTML":
                HtmlFileReferenceListUC htmlFileReferenceListUC = new HtmlFileReferenceListUC(settingOper);
                panel1.Controls.Clear();
                panel1.Controls.Add(htmlFileReferenceListUC);

                break;

            case "БД Аксес":
                DbAccessLinkListUC dbAccessLinkListUC = new DbAccessLinkListUC(settingOper);
                panel1.Controls.Clear();
                panel1.Controls.Add(dbAccessLinkListUC);

                break;

            case "БД MySql":
                DbMySqlLinkListUC dbMySqlLinkListUC = new DbMySqlLinkListUC(settingOper);
                panel1.Controls.Clear();
                panel1.Controls.Add(dbMySqlLinkListUC);

                break;


            case "БД MSSql":
                DbMSSqlLinkListUC dbMSSqlLinkListUC = new DbMSSqlLinkListUC(settingOper);
                panel1.Controls.Clear();
                panel1.Controls.Add(dbMSSqlLinkListUC);

                break;                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {

        string s = ex.Message;
        // throw;
    }

}
```

---

**Update_1**
In the source, I changed the value that falls in the `ActivePanel(string nameCheck)`.
I made the changes in the following scenario.
I'll look at an example: `case "Список ссылок файлов HTML"`.

**The initial state.**
Source - "Список ссылок файлов HTML".
case - "Список ссылок файлов HTML".
The result - "switch" does not work fo  r "Список ссылок файлов HTML".

**Test - 1**
Source - "List file".
case - "List file".
Result - "switch" works for "List file".

**Test - 2**
Source - "Список ссылок файлов HTML".
case - "Список ссылок файлов HTML".
The result - "switch" **works(!)** for the "Список ссылок файлов HTML".

I did such tests for all "case" and after that the "switch" works for all "case".
Even for "case" which have several non-English words.
If I did not do a test for "case", then "case" did not work with non-English words.

Comment: For any given switch statement execution, only a single "case" is going to execute. Were you expecting every case that *starts* with `nameCheck` to execute?

Comment: @JonSkeet Looking at the screenshots, the `"БД MySql"` case matches but the `"Список"` case doesn't. I'd guess that both strings look the same but aren't actually identical.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, in C# switch case does not have the "fallthrough" effect. Break will prevent a fallthrough and you can not write it without a break. With those non-english letters, normalisation might become an issue too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2 2 Strings are matched on binary level. But while two strings might **look** the same they might not be the same binary. Some Characters have ambigious representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations of your question.

a) You expect "fallthrough" behavior. Where you can have one case and all the following cases apply. I know native C++ has it. But unfortunately C# does not. That behavior requires the option to omit the break, but you do not get that option in C#. It was a design decision.

b) You are running into Normalization because you are using non-English Characters:
"Some Unicode characters have multiple equivalent binary representations consisting of sets of combining and/or composite Unicode characters. The existence of multiple representations for a single character complicates searching, sorting, matching, and other operations."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2

Matching - especially for string interning - is done on the binary level. And while two strings might **look** the same, they do not nessesarily **are** the same (binary speaking).

Comment: Actually you can "fallthrough" in C# via `goto case <case condition>` which can be used instead of `break`.

Comment: @ckuri: And that is just another reason I do not like goto and why it should be avoided in any programm. Unless of course you fancy making yourself (or whoever else will have to debug your code) to go insane. Wich I would never do, so I actively ban it from my thoughts.

Comment: @Christopher I do not understand English well. Therefore, I do not fully understand your answer. But this does not mean that I do not understand everything. I updated the question.
I would be grateful if you express your opinion in connection with the changes made.

Comment: @ckuri I updated the question.
I would be grateful if you express your opinion in connection with the changes made.

Comment: @eusataf: At it's core switch...case is just a lot of `if(nameCheck == "Список") [...] if (nameCheck == "Список ссылок файлов HTML"` checks. And if `==` does not return true, the case is never entered.